# Symfony 3 / Doctrine 2: Why my validator skipped?

Tags: php, validation, doctrine-orm, symfony

I want use callback validator and/or getter but all skipped in the simple entity:

AppBundle/Entity/Page.php:

```
public static function loadValidatorMetadata(ClassMetadata $metadata)
{      
    $metadata->addConstraint(new Assert\Callback('validate'));

     $metadata->addGetterConstraint('passwordLegal', new Assert\IsTrue(array(
        'message' => 'The password cannot match your first name',
    )));

}

public static function validate($object, ExecutionContextInterface $context)
{
    die('validate');
}

public function isPasswordLegal()
{
    die('isPasswordLegal');
}
```

`loadValidatorMetadata` executed, but `validate` and `isPasswordLegal` not. Why? Validation is enabled.

config.yml:

```
validation:      { enabled: true, enable_annotations: true }
```

I tried validation.yml:

```
AppBundle\Entity\Page:
constraints:
    - Callback: [validate]
```

Thank you.

Comment: how are you triggering validation?  Form submission?  validate?  saving the entity?

Comment: Form submission with Doctrine entity

Answer (score 0):

I found myself a working code:

```
 public static function loadValidatorMetadata(ClassMetadata $metadata)
{
    $callback = function ($object, ExecutionContextInterface $context) {
       $context->buildViolation($object->getTemplate().' sounds totally fake!')
        //->atPath('template')  //Global or Field error
        ->addViolation();
    };

    $metadata->addConstraint(new Assert\Callback($callback));
}
```

put this in the entity: `Yourbundle/Entity/EntityName.php`